# Преобразование данных перед отправкой из формы

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет. Есть форма, она создает новую запись в БД. 
Форма самая простая -

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

В форме есть данные, которые идут массивом, а именно 3 поля:

```
<label for="height">Длина:</label>
<input type="text" id="height" name="params[]">
<label for="country">Страна-производитель:</label>
<input type="text" id="country" name="params[]">
<label for="count">Количество цветов:</label>
<input type="text" id="count" name="params[]">
```

Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы перед отправкой к этим полям прибавлялись значения их лэйблов? Т.е. чтобы при вводе в длину значения "40 см" в БД записывалось "Длина: 40 см"?

Идеологически все понятно, на практике не хватает знаний :(

UPD: Для бОльшего понимания, объясню, для чего мне это надо:
У меня есть БД товаров, но для каждого товара есть свои свойства, которые мне нужно выводить. Создавать под каждый товар отдельные столбцы в БД - не есть хорошо, поэтому хочу создать один столбец свойств товара, куда будет записываться массив данных со свойствами, поскольку, к примеру, у плюшевых мишек не может быть длины стебля

Comment: а зачем в БД записывать см? а как потом сортировать по длине? мое мнение, лучше хранить в БД int, в миллиметрах, а потом перед выводом переводить их в сантиметры.

Comment: @Руслан Да, согласен, создам отдельный столбец с высотой, куда будет записываться лишь значение для цветов. Но проблема остается нерешенной - как перед отправкой данных в скрипт php добавить к значениям лейблы :(

Comment: Именно к значениям? Не лучше ли передать хэшем?  Типа `name="param[height]"`? Тогда не придётся вырезать `"Длинна: "` перед сохранением в бд.

Comment: судя по всему это заполнение карточки товара?

Comment: @Руслан да, верно

Comment: @Arnial не до конца понял, а что в итоге из этого выйдет? К примеру, будет 'name="param[height]"', это получится уже ассоциативный массив на выходе, верно? А затем уже добавлять значения по их ключу, т.е. если ключ - height, добавлять "Длина" и т.д.?

Comment: дело в том, что ваш подход совершенно не правильный... Если вы сделаете параметры товара массивом? то как вы в дальнейшем собираетесь их сортировать? для цветов товара обычно создают дополнительную таблицу, со связями... товар один а цветов много (один ко многим)... а потом на основании выборки определяют количество цветов.

Comment: И тут сейчас я понял, что я изначально ошибся :( Скажите, пожалуйста, а как тут поступить? Создать отдельную таблицу в БД с параметрами? Т.е. чтобы для каждого товара там создавались параметры? Или что мне в данном случае делать? 
По идее, все должно быть просто - Товары, категории, к каждой категории свои параметры и усе, но на деле все сложнее :(

Comment: Интернет магазин очень сложная штука, и от случая к случаю разная... Главный вопрос, на сколько велик будет ваш магазин? другой вопрос, какой тип товаров на нем будет? например магазин rozetka, его проектировали далеко не новички, и там 100% огромное количество таблиц и связей... я это все к тому, что нужно потренироваться на легких зачах, что бы набить руку и понять, как оно работает...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58224/discussion-between-alexxosipov-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много вот один из них: В форме надо добавить

```
<form onsubmit="mySubmit()">
 ....
</form>

function mySubmit(){
document.getElementsById("height").value = 'Длина' + document.getElementsById("height").value;
document.getElementsById("country").value = 'Страна' + document.getElementsById("country").value;
document.getElementsById("count").value = 'Колличество' + document.getElementsById("count").value;
}
```

можно оформить и получше, это решение в лоб